# Robot model in rviz is not following base link

Tags: ros, rviz, base-link, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using Gazebo with a simulated model with GPS, IMU and Odometry from the diff drive including the navsat and the
ukf node, the estimation is not correct yet, but I wonder about something else:

My robot model does not move in rviz.

In rviz I have set up the fixed frame to map.
The tfs are generated and I see them in Rviz, the tf links are moving around and the wheel tfs also rotate when doing so, but the rendered robot model keeps staying at the initial position. It is like that now, but before I could uncheck and check the checkbox of the robot state and the robot moved to the base_link to stick in that position till I do that unchecking and checking again. But that also does not work anymore.

Somehow it is just at the right place when setting fixed frame to base link, so the robot model is always following the fixed frame. But shouldn't it follow the "Robot Root Link"? (set to base_link)

Has anybody an idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance, for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203772/robot-model-in-rviz-is-not-following-base-link/) by [LucianTM](https://answers.ros.org/users/21714/luciantm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2015-02-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-02-25**:
What version of rviz/ROS?

**Comment by [LucianTM](https://answers.ros.org/users/21714/luciantm/) on 2015-02-26**:
The current one from the repository for Ubuntu 14.04 64 Bits.

```
[ INFO] [1424966599.084140166]: rviz version 1.11.4
[ INFO] [1424966599.084295977]: compiled against OGRE version 1.8.1 (Byatis)
[ INFO] [1424966600.923199210]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1424966600.923288004]: OpenGl version: 4.4
```

**Comment by [LucianTM](https://answers.ros.org/users/21714/luciantm/) on 2015-03-06**:
Can you confirm the behaviour or is there a problem with my model or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After looking in the turtlebot navigation rviz view I found my mistake.
I was using Robot State Plugin instead of Robot Model. When using the Robot Model plugin it just works fine.

---

Originally posted by [LucianTM](https://answers.ros.org/users/21714/luciantm/) with karma: 62 on 2015-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0